# Template inside of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange situation where I need to put a template inside of a template in my directive. The reason for this is that AngularJS will not read ng-repeat code inside of attributes.

In an ideal world, this is what my code would look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="phone in phones">
   <button popover="<div ng-repeat='friend in phone.friends'>{{friend.name}}</div>"></button>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this does not work because of the quotes around the popover attribute. This has led me down a pretty deep rabbit hole where I'm trying to put a template inside of a template like in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZA1uA1UOlU3cCH2mbE0X?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div my-popover></div>
```

Javascript:

```
angularApp.directive('myPopover', function( $compile) {
  var getTemplate = function()
  {
      var scope = {title: "other title"}; 
      var template = "<div> test template. title: {{title}}</div> ";
      return $compile(template)(scope); 
  }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<button class="btn btn-default" popover="{{content}}" popover-title="title">template</button>',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.content = getTemplate();
        }
    };
})
```

Unfortunately this does not work because AngularJs complains about a circular reference. Please help! (this has been taking me all day)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, but from the *look of it* you might want check out the `transclude` option for directives.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> use transclude: true when you want to create a directive that wraps
>   arbitrary content.

If you use transclude, you can store the popover content inside the button, and "forward" that content to where you want it using the ng-transclude directive.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
<button>
    <div ng-repeat='friend in phone.friends'>{{friend.name}}</div>
</button>
```

You can see some examples in action in [the guide to directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: That sounds interesting. To clarify, I need to get a template inside of popover="[[ content goes here ]]". The attributes seem to be the difficult part because I can't put an ng-repeat in there. Would a transclude help with this? I'm finding the documentation pretty confusing.

Comment: If it's ok if the popover content isn't defined as an attribute value but as the content of the button element, then it should help, yes.

Comment: See if you can find any other tutorials or examples using transclude. I found this [example](http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/) for instance.